# Tensorflow - import error in CIFAR tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, importerror

Recently, I installed tensorflow and got python import error in CIFAR tutorial.
I'm using Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 2.7.

```
$ python cifar10_train.py
```

> Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "cifar10_train.py", line 120, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>     File "/Users/sunwoo/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
>       sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>     File "cifar10_train.py", line 116, in main
>       train()
>     File "cifar10_train.py", line 76, in train
>       class _LoggerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SessionRunHook'

How can I import tf.train.SessionRunHook?

Comment: Can you give me more  detail code? I can not figure out what is happen with one line.

Comment: My code is here. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [`master` branch of `cifar10_train.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py), with an older installed version of TensorFlow (0.11 or earlier). The `master` branch was [recently modified](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/45009de073a203f54bff7cec0ea83f88c48237b9) to use a new API, which wasn't available in TensorFlow 0.11 or earlier.

There are two ways to fix this problem. Either upgrade TensorFlow to version 0.12 or later, or check out [the `r0.11` branch of the TensorFlow source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.11), and use [the version of `cifar10_train.py` from that branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can run `cihar10_train.py` at `v0.11.0rc2` tag.